# Conversion of Excel into .pdf while using 'IncludeDocProperties' field

Tags: excel, matlab, pdf

I use the following code in MATLAB to convert an Excel worksheet into PDF, but I am getting the `info (name)` of the Excel file at the top of the PDF.

How can I get rid of it?
I know there is an optional field `IncludeDocProperties`, but I am not sure how to use it?

```
hExcel = actxserver('Excel.Application');
hWorkbook = hExcel.Workbooks.Open(sprintf('%s',excel_filepath));     
hWorksheet = hWorkbook.Sheets.Item(1);
hWorksheet.ExportAsFixedFormat('xlTypePDF',pdf_filepath); 
hWorkbook.Close; 
hExcel.Quit; 
hExcel.delete;
```

Comment: i have tried your code but don't see anything as you mentioned. Can you provide more details of what you want and what you got? Typically, `pdf_filepath` should be the path to the pdf file, including the pdf file name, e.g `C:\Test\test.pdf`

Comment: it is the path to the pdf file and the pdf file is written correctly. the problem i have is that i get on the top left corner of the pdf the name of the excel file. I suspect it has to do with "IncludeDocProperties" optional field, which i dont know how to use., thank you ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, convert to `pdf` by `ExportAsFixedFormat` method will give you a `pdf` file that looks exactly like what you get when you **print out** the `excel` file.

So, the `info (name)` that you mentioned is not created by `Matlab`, but by `Excel`. You have to open the file in `Excel`, and check if the Header/Footer is turned off or not. If you have Header/Footer turned on for the file, then the `pdf` exported through `Matlab` will also have that info (maybe file name, or page number, or author name etc.).